# Vegetable Cellulose

Tags: botany, nutrition, ethnobiology

I'm a pharmacy student working on my thesis. I just want to ask the probable sources of vegetable cellulose found in vegetable capsule? Note: I'm referring to the capsule itself not for its possible content. Thanks.

Comment: There are "vegetarian" capsules?? I didn't know about this..

Answer (score 5):

Vegetarian capsules are made of hydroxypropylmethylcellulose (also called [hypromellose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypromellose)). The cellulose from which this material is prepared is usually from tree fiber, commonly from pine or poplar species (as noted [here](http://capsuleconnection.com/capsule-ingredients/)).